# front-page.php not working properly in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am new to web development and not really sure how to fix this issue:

I am running into an issue for a site which i am currently running on my own machine in wordpress and added following lines in the header.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/marquee.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/farinspace/jquery.imgpreload.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/marquee.js"></script>
```

Than i created front-page.php file which looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="/images/photos/london.jpg" alt="London"   width="100" />
<div class="marquee_container">
        <div class="marquee_photos"></div>
        <div class="marquee_caption">
            <div class="marquee_caption_content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="marquee_nav"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="marquee_panels">
        <!-- Panel -->
        <div class="marquee_panel">
            <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="/images/photos/london.jpg" alt="London" width="100" />
            <div class="marquee_panel_caption">
                <img class="marquee_flag" src="/images/template/flag_england.jpg" width="20" height="13" />
                <h2>London</h2>
                <p>Fusce neque dolor adipiscing sed consectetuer et lacinia sit amet quam. Suspendisse wisi quam consectetuer in blandit sed suscipit eu eros.</p>
                <p><a href="#">Check it out!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My directory structure is like this:
front-page.php
images/photos
images/template
includes

When I run the file in firefox, I dont see anything below the menu. None of the div or javascript is running. When I try running sample para in front-page.php it shows up.

Any help in debugging this would be great

Comment: Have you set a static front page in the back end and have you chosen to use front-page.php as your page template? Also is front-page.php in the root folder of wordpress or the theme folder?

Comment: yeah I have set the front page as static at the back end and now I am using front-page.php .. The front-page.php is in the theme root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the answer which resolved this question so posting the following code for others reference which solved it:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
   // register your script location and dependencies
   wp_register_script('custom_script',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', array('jquery')
    );
   // enqueue the script
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');


   //add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');

   // register your script location and dependencies
   wp_register_script('custom_script1',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/farinspace/jquery.imgpreload.min.js',
       array('jquery')
    );
   // enqueue the script
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_script1');

  // add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');

  // register your script location and dependencies
   wp_register_script('custom_script2',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/front-page.js',
       array('jquery')
    );
   // enqueue the script
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_script2'); 

   if (is_page_template('our-story.php')) {
       wp_register_script('custom_script3',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/parallax.js',
       array('jquery')
    );
   // enqueue the script
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_script3'); 

   }

}

   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');


?>
```